# Should I be using "torch.set_grad_enabled"?

Tags: pytorch

I've never seen any code examples using this line during training: torch.set_grad_enabled

I've also never used it before. I read that it helps conserve memory, but if that was the case, shouldn't most people be using this?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be using "torch.set_grad_enabled"?
> I read that it helps conserve memory

I believe your question is about the usage of `torch.set_grad_enabled(False)`. This method invocation is not for optimization but rather to turn off gradient computations. For example, when running inference on a PyTorch model, gradient calculations may not be required at all. In such cases, you can disable Autograd with set_grad_enabled instead of removing `grad_fn` for each parameter. The memory conservation occurs because gradients are not stored in memory.

This [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/introyt/autogradyt_tutorial.html) helps you understand Autograd.